# Transferring luggage. Transit visa

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, air-canada, philippine-airlines

I am flying from Manila to Tokyo, Narita with Philippine Airlines. Then onward to Calgary, Canada with Air Canada. When transferring in Tokyo, do I need to collect my baggage and clear immigration and customs? Even if I don't, I found they use different terminals. Is it possible to go from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1 airside?

Comment: Do you have one or two tickets for this?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: You need to clear security but that's all.

Moving luggages between airlines like this is called interlining and Air Canada [interline partners](https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/book/routes-and-partners/star-alliance-and-other-airline-partners.html) include Philippine Airlines (PR).

[image]

There is an inter terminal [shuttle](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/connect/inter/) so you can certainly stay airside:

> This page provides information on how to connect between international flights without collecting your baggage or entering Japan.

Comment: This connecting flights has only one E- number ticket because i booked at the same time.oh great im relieve and less worries for all answers i got.Those airline representatives made my day inconvenient whole day.I callep PR and the rep told me i need to pick my luggage because its PR dont not interline aggreement with Air Canada.So im thinking to change my iterinary then but tell now dont know yet. Good thing there are some good heart to help for my inquiry.